# How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> elements?

Tags: javascript

How can I read the line break from a value with JavaScript and replace all the line breaks with `<br />` elements?

Example:

A variable passed from PHP as below:

```
  "This is man.

     Man like dog.
     Man like to drink.

     Man is the king."
```

I would like my result to look something like this after the JavaScript converts it:

```
  "This is man<br /><br />Man like dog.<br />Man like to drink.<br /><br />Man is the king."
```

Comment: Something wrong with your original question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784313/read-line-break-in-a-string-with-javascript

Comment: You could also do nl2br($string) in PHP before you send it to JavaScript.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close the earlier question, as this has a better example.

Comment: He should edit the initial question then

Comment: I came here from a misguided understanding to what was going on with .text().  See https://stackoverflow.com/q/35238362/1467396 if that's what you're doing, too

Answer (score 1524, accepted):

This will turn all returns into HTML

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
```

In case you wonder what ?: means.
It is called a non-capturing group. It means that group of regex within the parentheses won't be saved in memory to be referenced later.
You can check out these threads for more information:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11530881/5042169
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36524555/5042169

Comment: Just additional note: `str.replace("\n", '<br />')` (first argument is a regular string) will replace only first occurrence.

Comment: Another version (to replace multiple line-breaks): str.replace(/(\n)+/g, '<br />');

Comment: @SergeS. Thanks for that extra comment. Just saved me a TONNE of time! [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yPSEZ/7/)

Comment: @EleventyOne thanks for the jsfiddle, makes life much simpler for me!

Comment: @SergeS., `String#replace` coerces its first argument from `String` to an escaped `RegExp` instance, with no flags. `str.replace('\n', '<br />');` is equivalent to `str.replace(new RegExp('\n'), '<br />');`

Comment: @eyelidlessness, Thanks for explanation! Yep, this is the reason. Intuitively it's easy to assume that `String#replace` expects first argument to be a regular string, and it will replace all occurrences by default. That's why many mistakes are made with replacing strings in JS ;)

Comment: @eyelidlessness - Would you consider updating your answer to use the expression `('\r?\n','g')`, since some systems use `\r`?

Comment: @Conexion, `\r?\n` is not correct either. Some other systems use `\r` alone. I'll update for all cases.

Comment: Here is a test case compare to `str.split("\n").join("<br />")` http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-replace-regex RegEx seems slightly faster

Comment: \r?\n|\r is slightly shorter than \r\n|\r|\n

Comment: There is no slash needed in break tag these days.

Comment: Not sure this solution OK. consider this string "a \\n b \n c" which we want to be: "a \n b <br/> c", but: we will get: "a \<br/> b <br/> c"

Comment: I stumble upon this character in my json response: `↵` This is basically `u21B5` [link](https://graphemica.com/%E2%86%B5). @eyelidlessness solution does also work in this case.

Comment: Why do `/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g` instead of just `/\r\n|\r|\n/g`? It seems like it does exactly the same thing. What's the advantage of the non-capturing group?

Comment: @Clonkex using `?:` will match whatever is in the group, but not return it, while the rest of the expression that matched will return, which is useful in some cases, but I actually don't see a difference in using it here, as nothing gets returned—just replaced ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Is adding the non-capturing group worth the improvement in performance for the degrease in readability?

Comment: What's wron with ```[\r\n]+``` ?

Answer (score 579):

If your concern is just displaying linebreaks, you could do this with CSS.

```html
<div style="white-space: pre-line">Some test
with linebreaks</div>
```

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5bvtL6do/2/

**Note**: Pay attention to code formatting and indenting, since `white-space: pre-line` will display **all** newlines (except for the last newline after the text, see fiddle).

Comment: I came here looking for the regex and left with this.  In lots of occasions this is what people are looking for.  We use linebreaks for emails and need to display what the email looked line in html, sometimes. Perfecto. Thanks for looking at the question in a different light

Comment: This might work for actual line breaks, but what if I have "\n"s like in the question? Can I solve this by CSS, too?

Comment: Instead of 
`white-space: pre-wrap;`
I prefer use
`white-space: pre-line;` (to not add a final break line after all)

Comment: looks good but what about a giant space before the first line? weird

Comment: @Toolkit good point, you can omit this space by not adding a line break after the opening div tag or with the infamous <!--
--> trick.

Comment: Amazing. I couldn't even get the JS approach to work. This works!

Comment: Unfortunately not supported by IE11 and Edge. https://caniuse.com/#search=white-space

Comment: @MarkHewitt It does work in IE11 and Edge. I don't know why caniuse states otherwise, but I just tested in IE11 and also https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp states that it works and also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space.

Comment: @bersling You're right, it does work. I loaded up the Mozilla page on IE 11 and Edge 16, both on Windows 10, and they work just fine. I wonder if the caniuse data relates to the following? "Method of customizing the width of the tab character. Only effective using 'white-space: pre' or 'white-space: pre-wrap'." In the uncertainty, I'm glad I went with paulslater19's solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/8412950/600960

Comment: Excellent.  I did not even think to ask about a CSS solution.  Thank you very much.

Comment: the regex did not work for me ! but this did ! thank youuuuu

Comment: @jpmottin I think your version is closer to what the question author was looking for, so I changed my answer to `white-space: pre-line` as well. Thank you!

Comment: @Toolkit you can use JS `.trim()` function to remove white space before and after. Or you can use `.trimStart() / .trimLeft()` to remove white space at the start.

Comment: All of the methods above this answer converted \n to <br> just fine but none rendered the break. They all got URI encoded when actually displayed in the text. But, the simple CSS rule in this answer worked perfect! Needs more upvotes!!

Answer (score 90):

Without regex:

```
str = str.split("\n").join("<br />");
```

Comment: If you do "\\n" you'll avoid issues with splitting on just the "n".

Comment: @CrowderSoup hmm? I just tried it and `\\n` doesn't match on a new line, because it's looking for `backslash` + `n`.

Comment: I made a test case. RegEx is slightly faster, but check out for yourself http://jsperf.com/split-join-vs-replace-regex

Comment: I found this answer did not work unless the slash was escaped. For example: str = str.split("\n").join("<br />");

Comment: @ACOMIT001 I guess that depends whether the string has a new line or a blackslash and n?

Answer (score 48):

This works for input coming from a textarea

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');
```

Comment: It's the best answer for me because you didn't forget the \r, which is used on some systems

Comment: This is the best answer for this question. But I will just go with <br> not <br />. See this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br

Answer (score 13):

If the accepted answer isn't working right for you then you might try.

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\n','g'), '<br />')
```

It worked for me.

Comment: `new RegExp('\n', 'g')` is identical to `/\n/g` (except for some minutiae about using primitive literals versus their constructors).

Comment: whatever the reason, this worked for me but the accepted answer didn't

Comment: Ah, same here... but my mistake was attempting to specify `/\n/g` as a string!

Answer (score 11):

Shortest code supporting the most common [EOL styles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation) `\r`, `\n`, `\r\n` and using HTML5 `<br>`:

```
s.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, '<br>')
```

Answer (score 8):

It is also important to encode the rest of the text in order to protect from possible script injection attacks

```
function insertTextWithLineBreaks(text, targetElement) {
    var textWithNormalizedLineBreaks = text.replace('\r\n', '\n');
    var textParts = textWithNormalizedLineBreaks.split('\n');

    for (var i = 0; i < textParts.length; i++) {
        targetElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textParts[i]));
        if (i < textParts.length - 1) {
            targetElement.appendChild(document.createElement('br'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like it but I don't have or want a target element. Can this be done where the return value is a string?

Answer (score 8):

Regardless of the system:

```
my_multiline_text.replace(/$/mg,'<br>');
```

Comment: Caution: This will append a '<br>' tag to any string, regardless if there's a ‘\n‘ in it.

Comment: You could fix the error @mkoeller mentioned by adding this after the first replacement: `.replace(/\<br\>$, '')`, which will remove that last `<br>` ("search for `<br>` that touches the end of the string (`$`), and replace it with an empty string (`''`)")

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me when value came from a TextBox:

```
string.replace(/\n|\r\n|\r/g, '<br/>');
```

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who just want to allow max. 2 `<br>` in a row, you can use this:

```
let text = text.replace(/(\r?\n){2,}/g, '<br><br>');
text = text.replace(/(\r?\n)/g, '<br>');
```

First line: Search for `\n` OR `\r\n` where at least 2 of them are in a row, e.g. `\n\n\n\n`. Then replace it with 2 `br`

Second line: Search for all single `\r\n` or `\n` and replace them with `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

if you send the variable from PHP, you can obtain it with this before sending:

```
$string=nl2br($string);
```

Comment: This should be selected answer thanks for the simple straightforward answer .

Answer (score 0):

> It will replace all new line with break

`str = str.replace(/\n/g, '<br>')`

> If you want to replace all new line with single break line

`str = str.replace(/\n*\n/g, '<br>')`

> Read more about Regex : https://dl.icewarp.com/online_help/203030104.htm
>   this will help you everytime.

Comment: It is also possible to use a regex like this `str = str.replace(/\n+/g, '<br>')` for the second case

Answer (score 0):

Not answering the specific question, but I am sure this will help *someone*...

If you have output from PHP that you want to render on a web page using JavaScript (perhaps the result of an Ajax request), and you just want to retain white space and line breaks, consider just enclosing the text inside a `<pre></pre>` block:

```
var text_with_line_breaks = retrieve_some_text_from_php();
var element = document.querySelectorAll('#output');
element.innerHTML = '<pre>' + text_with_line_breaks + '</pre>';
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a config in PHP that was being passed in from the Controller. (Laravel)

Example: PHP Config

```
'TEXT_MESSAGE' => 'From:Us\nUser: Call (1800) 999-9999\nuserID: %s'
```

Then in javascript using es6 reduce. notice I had to have two `\\` or the output was not being replace correctly. Here are the parameters that are assoicated with the reduce function

- previousValue (the value resulting from the previous call to
  callbackfn)
- currentValue (the value of the current element)
- currentIndex Optional
- array (the array to traverse) Optional

```
//p is previousVal
//c is currentVal
String.prototype.newLineReplace = function(){
    return [...arguments].reduce((p,c) => p.replace(/\\n/g,c), this);
}
```

Here is how i used it in my script.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var config = @json($config);</script>

config.TEXT_MESSAGE.newLineReplace("<br />")
```

of course you could just called it on a javascript sring like...

```
let a = 'From:Us\nUser: Call (1800) 999-9999\nuserID: %s'
var newA = a.newLineReplace("<br />")

//output
'From:Us<br />User: Call (1800) 999-9999<br />userID: %s'
```