# Javascript: replacing newlines with <br/> working in FF and SAFARI and not working in IE

Tags: javascript

Code in the post has been modified.

I was thinking that replacing \n with 
 with javascript was quite a simple task, but it seems not to be so. Posts in [Ask Ben](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/161-Ask-Ben-Javascript-Replace-And-Multiple-Lines-Line-Breaks.htm) or [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/replace-all-line-break-in-a-string-with-br-tag-in-javascript) suggest that something as simple as:

```
var myRe = new RegExp(/\r?\n/g); // to avoid the re literal caching problem
lDes = $("div.descr").html(); 
lDes = lDes.replace (myRe, "<br/>"); 
lDes = lDes.replace (/(http:\/\/\S+)/g, "<a target=\"blank\" href=\"$1\">$1</a>"); 
$("div.descr").html(lDes);
```

will get the job done. Indeed, this work in FF and Safari but not in IE.

Or, using  [postie](http://pastie.org/948352)  (great hint!)

Text has been created in a textarea and then stored in a database, then retrieved without further processing. It works using FF on windows and Safari on Mac. IE on windows, nada. Is it a major bug in my head? Is it a JQuery issue?

Have some idea about how to solve this? And possible reason for?

Many thanks

Comment: Exactly what you have works fine for me on IE7 in an HTML page. Your best bet is to create an isolated, self-contained test case (here's a starting point: http://pastie.org/948317) that replicates the issue.

Comment: @Daniel can you post the code you use to actually get the text from the database into the page?

Comment: Ah - so it looks like you're dropping the text into a `<div>`, then getting it back out again.  I suspect then that that might be your problem: IE may be giving you the text back without any newline characters at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of putting the text in question into a `<div>` on the page, perhaps you can put it directly into a block of Javascript.  Now that will require that you have some server-side code to "protect" the Javascript string constant syntax, which is a strangely rare facility but easy to create.  You just have to make sure that quote characters, as well as control characters and characters outside the 7-bit range, are appropriately "escaped" the way Javascript expects string constants to look.

Here's what it'd look like in one of my applications.  This is a Java/JSP example, so probably not what you're using, and of course the "escape" function I call is my own invention, but just so you see what I mean:

```
var theText = '${pointy:escapeJS(data.theText)}';
$('#target').html(theText.replace(/\n/g, '<br>'));
```

Of course if you're receiving the text as an AJAX response, things are simpler.

Now that example leaves out something important: you have to make sure the text is HTML-escaped before dropping it into the document.  Perhaps that's been done server-side, or if not you can do that in Javascript too:

```
$('#target').html(theText
  .replace(/\r/g, '') // get rid of carriage returns
  .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
  .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
  .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
  .replace(/\n\n/g, '\n&nbsp;\n')
  .replace(/\n/g, '<br>')
);
```

(There are better/faster ways to do HTML escaping of course; that's just an example.)  Note that I stick explicit blank padding between successive newlines - that's something I cribbed from some code I have and I think I did that because successive `<br>` elements without intervening "stuff" might not give multiple blank lines in the result; not sure however.

Comment: Your guess is correct. FF preserves \n in getting the <div> content, in IE there is no \n anywhere. That's quite an issue ...

Comment: @Daniel: Not really. According to the specification, all whitespace characters (including `\n`) outside of a couple of specific places (like `pre`) are combined and treated as a single space. It's not a great surprise that IE's `innerHTML` (which is ultimately what jQuery is using in its `html` method) should reflect that. (Don't forget to accept Pointy's answer if it was the correct one.)

Comment: You are right. The answer is good, but it adds complexity to the rendering. I am inclined to render as <pre> all the <div> content... But the advice is good, I work on it.

Answer (score 1):

What DOCTYPE are you using? It may be that, depending on the DOCTYPE (i.e., not using XHTML), `<BR/>` should be rendered as `<BR>`. IE could be in some weird state of compatibility or quirks mode, etc.

Comment: Good point, but doesn't make any difference, if the page is HTML, `<br/>` will still work, the slash at the end gets ignored.