# JavaScript replace \n with <br />

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

```
var messagetoSend = $.trim(document.getElementById("msgText").value);
messagetoSend = messagetoSend.replace("\n", "<br />");
alert(messagetoSend);
```

Given input:

```
Line 1


Line 2




Line 3
```

This alerts:

```
Line 1<br />


Line 2




Line 3
```

When I expect it to alert:

```
Line 1<br /><br /><br />Line 2<br /><br /><br /><br /><br />Line 3
```

Comment: given that the string is html and not plaintext just style it so that \n causes a line break, `white-space: pre;` otherwise you'll end up corruting entities that contain \n,  if it's actually text, congrats you now own an XSS vuln.

Answer (score 225, accepted):

You need the /g for [global matching](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html)

`replace(/\n/g, "<br />");`

This works for me for `\n`  - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20129925/295783) if you might have `\r\n`

*NOTE:* [The dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/295783) is the most complete answer for any combination of `\r\n`, `\r` or `\n`

```js
var messagetoSend = document.getElementById('x').value.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
console.log(messagetoSend);
```

```html
<textarea id="x" rows="9">
    Line 1
    
    
    Line 2
    
    
    
    
    Line 3
</textarea>
```

**UPDATE**

It seems some visitors of this question have text with the breaklines escaped as

> some text**\r\n**over more than one line"

In that case you need to escape the slashes:

`replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br />");`

NOTE: All browsers will ignore `\r` in a string when rendering.

Comment: I changed it to this, it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't replace anything.

Comment: The "g" one still only adds in one <br />  The regexp one doesn't do anything

Comment: Don't know why, but for me `replace(/\\n/g,"<br />")` works. I'm a bit confused. :/

Comment: That is the textual representation of a newline. Is this pure JS or a string in php or similar

Comment: Same problem in .NET ASPX with jQuery - .replace(/\\r\\n/g, "<br />") did the trick.

Comment: So something on the server already escaped the breaklines

Comment: I added two more semicolon like `str.replace('/\n/g','')` makes it does not work.Others note this.

Comment: @inOut This`;` is a semicolon. Your single quotes breaks the regular expression

Comment: Github copilot suggested me this 

Comment: @AliN11 this answer was suggested by GitHub copilot? Cool :)

Comment: @mplungjan I created a function named `ln2br`. Then Copilot suggested the regex at beginning of this answer :))

Answer (score 105):

Handles either type of line break

```
str.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n','g'), '<br />');
```

Comment: This solves the whole issue because previous ones were somehow replacing my last character on every line.

Comment: Doesn't handle `\r` without `\n`.

Answer (score 10):

Use a regular expression for `.replace()`.:

```
messagetoSend = messagetoSend.replace(/\n/g, "<br />");
```

If those linebreaks were made by windows-encoding, you will also have to replace the `carriage return`.

```
messagetoSend = messagetoSend.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br />");
```

Comment: I changed it to this, it doesn't seem to work.  It doesn't replace anything.

Comment: @Tom: probably windows linebreaks ? I updated the code, try with carriage return aswell.

Comment: It is \n and not \\n - I think my answer has handled this. \r can be ignored - the browser will