# Convert JSON \n to HTML <br> tag

Tags: javascript, html, json, line-breaks, youtube-data-api

I've been developing a website using the YouTube A.P.I.

Within the `description` tag in the JSON file are line breaks `\n`

I need to convert these tags to HTML format

```
VideoDescriptions.push(item.snippet.description);

["Example description\nPlease click the link", "Another example description\nMore info"]
```

**Edit:**

This question is NOT a duplicate of the linked article because:

- It's using the YouTube API to retrieve data
- It's necessary to edit from an array rather than the string (as
  described in the article)
- The answers in either question could lead to different results and
  may not apply

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript replace \n with <br />](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076466/javascript-replace-n-with-br)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use string `replace` in javascript:

```js
var items = ["Example description\nPlease click the link\n\n", "Another example description\nMore info"];
console.clear();


var changed = items.map(i => i.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')).join('');
var div = document.querySelector("#test");
div.innerHTML = changed;
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Guess I was just using the replace tag wrong, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Fun fact, if you set the content of your tag by .innerText, rather than innerHTML.
All the \n characters will be converted into < br > tag for you.

Ex:

> document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0].innerText = 'New text with a \nLine break.'

Comment: Wouldn't I have to apply this to each string in the array?

Comment: I mean you can keep all the strings intact, and use innerText when you want to output them on the page.

Comment: I get it. Are there any other advantages to using `.innerText` ?

Comment: It does what it does. And it is just handy in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably create individual nodes from each line instead of using `<br>` as it allows more flexibility. You could do something like this:

```js
var description = ["Example description\nPlease click the link", "Another example description\nMore info"];
var fragment = description.reduce(function (frag, line) {
    var parts = line.split('\n');
    var container = document.createElement('div');
    var firstLine = document.createElement('p');
    var secondLine = document.createElement('a');
    firstLine.textContent = parts[0];
    secondLine.textContent = parts[1];
    secondLine.href = '#';
    container.appendChild(firstLine);
    container.appendChild(secondLine);
    frag.appendChild(container);
    return frag;
}, document.createDocumentFragment());
document.querySelector('.parent').appendChild(fragment);
```

```html
<div class="parent"></div>
```

Here we take the description and reduce it into a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) containing a  container element with two children per item in the description array.

Using methods like [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) will prevent the XSS-attack vector (even if the descriptions are in your control, don't create possible XSS vulnerabilities for fun).

Answer (score -1):

You can use a javascript replace function, and replace items by your needs:

```js
 String.prototype.replaceAll = function(search, replacement) {
    var target = this;
    return target.split(search).join(replacement);
    };

var test = ["yes, this is my example\n", "goodbye"];
console.log(test[0].replaceAll('\n', '<br>'))
```