# javascript error with carriage return and newline

Tags: java, javascript, replaceall

I have following string in Java:

```
"this is text1\r\nthis is text2\r\nthis is text3"
```

I am replacing `\r\n` with `<br/>` as follows:

```
String temp = "this is  text1\r\nthis is text2\r\nthis is text3"
temp = temp.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", "<br/>");
```

which produces the following string: `"is text1 this is text2 this is text3"`

now, I want to send it to JavaScript element as follows:

```
var desc_str = "<%=temp%>";
document.getElementById('proc_desc').value = desc_str;
```

The output from Java is fine, but after passing to HTML element, I am getting JavaScript error "unterminated String literal", I am not finding the clue, please help.

Comment: Not familiar with Java but have you tried encoding as JSON?

Comment: @Ian that will solve the problem for scriplets usage but don't think it will help on the JavaScript client side.

Comment: Why don't you include the generated JavaScript code here in your question? Have you even looked at it? I'm thinking the answer would be really obvious from looking at the generated JavaScript.

Comment: Do you have any stray quotation marks when the value is printed out?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't gotten all of the line breaks out of your String.

You might find this post helpful:
[How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: I found the solution, the problem is escape/unescape of \r\n while passing the java string to javascript variable. There is no need to replace the \r\n with <br/> but just unescape the java string tmpProPrDesc = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript(tmpProPrDesc); var desc_str = "<%=tmpProPrDesc%>";
document.getElementById('proc_desc').value = desc_str;