# Pulling Content From Text File Not Working JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, xmlhttprequest

My code in my HTML file:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>Notes</title>
<script>
function PullNotes() {
var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile.open("GET", "notes.txt", true);
txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile.readyState === 4 || txtFile.status == 200) {
        allText = txtFile.responseText;
    }

    document.getElementById('notetext').innerHTML = allText;
}
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="notetext"><p>Failed.</p></div>
<input type="button" value="Pull Notes" onClick="PullNotes()">
</body>
</html>
```

When I click the button. Nothing happened.

If you're wondering why it says "Failed" it's so I know that the JavaScript didn't update.

Thanks,
~BN

Comment: is notes.txt on your file system or on the http server?  if you are accessing this html page via http://foo.com/index.html then notes.txt needs to be @ http://foo.com/notes.txt.  You also need to `send()` the request I think.

Comment: Put this in your if-block: `document.getElementById('notetext').innerHTML = allText;`

Comment: @SB. Server. I tried it on both local and server.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `txtFile.send()` after you assign the `onreadystatechange` property.  Check [this](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) out.

Also, notes.txt must be in a sibling location to the html file you are loading.  I.e. foo.com/index.html -> foo.com/notes.txt

Your code becomes:

```
function PullNotes() {
    var txtFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    txtFile.open("GET", "notes.txt", true);
    txtFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (txtFile.readyState === 4 || txtFile.status == 200) {
            allText = txtFile.responseText;
        }

        document.getElementById('notetext').innerHTML = allText;
    }; // end onreadystatchange prop
    // send the request
    txtFile.send();
}
```

Comment: Where should I put it? The line right after .onreadystatechange?

Comment: Thanks!!! The txtFile.send(); Fixed it! But my text file is multi-lined and the whole thing comes as one line.

Comment: @Brandon - that's because you're inserting it as html, and HTML ignores the newlines.  You could replace all `\n` with `<br/>` as a hack - see this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: Or you could put it inside a `<pre>` block.

Comment: Can you put every two lines in a separate div?

Comment: Or maybe one line even.