# How to print multiline in document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm fetching the data from my database through 'fetching' datatype, 'Features' is a row, element in the 'Features' row has Multiline data.

eg:

Simultaneous HD video and image recording, geo-tagging, touch focus.

face and smile detection.

image stabilization, HDR.

php

```
function mf(){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($fetching)){
        echo $row['Features'];
}
}
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML = "<?php mf(); ?>";
```

Html

```
<div id="idname"> </div>
```

Here mf function has Features row element shown in example. When I try to execute, no output in webpage, If I remove new line and write whole element in a single line it works, if it is multiline, then data is not showing up in webpage.
Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Because the string has newlines, the JavaScript looks like this:

```
... .innerHTML = "text text
text
text"
```

Which is not valid JS. In PHP, replace the newlines with `<br />`, so `innerHTML` will parse instead of a syntax error.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
But, I cant update my whole database by removing all new lines and adding <br /> it takes lot of time.
Any alternate solution please

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `\n` new line character, update the `innerText` property. If you insist on using the `innerHTML` property, you must replace the `\n` characters with HTML break tags `<br />`

http://jsfiddle.net/6QnQG/

Unless you are certain that the data doesn't potentially contain malicious HTML or don't need to output html tags, I'd recommend you go with innerText.

`document.getElementById('idname').innerText = "<?php mf(); ?>";`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But, I cant update my whole database by removing all new lines and adding /n it takes lot of time. Any alternate solution please

Comment: @sailesh \n is new line. I'm confused, does your output have \n new line characters or not? If yes, innerText will work for you. If not, then you don't have a multiline content. See update

Comment: @cbayran Thanks for the reply, but data in feature has new lines as shown in example. I was unable to view that data in features in browser, instead I can view it in page source

Comment: @sailesh and doing innerText on this data doesn't work? ```document.getElementById('idname').innerText = "<?php mf(); ?>";```

Comment: What does your new line character look like in the page source? If you  have the \n new line character in your String, the innerText property will work.

Comment: Nope, not working. I can give you my teamviewer id, where I can clearly tell you what problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the new lines with `<br/>` in javascript.

```
var str = "<?php mf(); ?>";
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
document.getElementById("idname").innerHTML = str;
```

regular expression taken from:
[How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)