# encode line feed character in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

i have this text:

```
this is a sample
text
```

Apparently, after "sample" there is a Line feed character (ENTER). How can i encode JUST those characters and not the whole string. When i use encodeURI the whole string gets encoded
What i want to do is to get a string like "this is a sample%0Atext"
Thanks

Comment: What's the *real* goal ?

Comment: Because this text is an SMS text, that i have to post to my provider. All characters have to be  NOT encoded, just special chars like enter, ', " etc

Comment: How are you sending them ?

Comment: i am sending it with http /POST

Comment: How about replacing newline character ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Answer (score 0):

So double url encoding - where the API requires raw input of %250A for a \n ?

```
str = str.replace(/[\r\n]/g, function(m) { return escape(m); });
```