# Adding line breaks on "paragraph text" when emailing HTML from google forms response

Tags: html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I am making a google form that automatically sends out an HTML email upon submission of a new response.

A few fields of the google form are "paragraph text" which might actually have more than one paragraph. It records on the google spreadsheet within the cell like this:

```
Text first line
Second line of text 
3rd line of text
```

But when the email is generated it will show like this:

> Text first line Second line of text 3rd line of text

How could make it so the code would look like this: (add line breaks)

```
Text first line <br/>
Second line of text <br/>
3rd line of text
```

The snippet of code I am using to grab the cell data and add to the email message looks like this

```
message += e.namedValues[columns[5]];
```

Comment: Other possible dup: [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](//stackoverflow.com/questions/784539). This may be more suitable for what you're trying to do, since the text read from the form submission should have newline characters in it already (`\n`).

Comment: FWIW, _I_ didn't downvote it, and would have no idea that you have another account that you forgot the pw for. Note that in the time _I_ spent checking for duplicates, I found [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8412950/1677912) which is EXACTLY what you have posted as an answer... thereby proving that (a) your question was a duplicate and (b) you were pointed to the solution. As a long-time user, I'm sure you remember that we are supposed to be civil here - so I assume you meant "Thank you."

Comment: @GuacaWholy If you have another account, I'm sure that Stack Exchange can help you reclaim the password to it (and therefore your rep) by using the [Contact Us](http://stackoverflow.com/contact) link at the bottom of every page. Usually they're quite responsive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that all other solutions didn't account for numbers and dates and it was breaking the code due the data within a single cell being a "mixed bag".

The solution was to actually make the cell into a string and then split and join. This will also replace ALL breaks not only the first one.

```
 var br = e.namedValues[columns[5]].toString().split('\n').join('<br/>');
 message += br;
```

So basically:

```
e.namedValues[columns[5]] // is my selected cell
split('\n') // splits at the breaks (google uses \n )
join('<br/>') // joins everything together replacing the \n breaks with  the html break tag
```

Hope this helps anyone more than down voting