# Jquery line break removal is not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have this code That is reponsible to load values inside my control

actualy line breaks are appearing , so i am replacing all the line breaks with following code

```
/* Specific method to load values from a radio group */

load_values.radiogroup = function (ctrl_type, ctrl_id) {            // debugger;
    var form = $("#theForm");
    var div_ctrl = $("#" + ctrl_id);
    var options = '';
    var ctrls = div_ctrl.find("div").find("label");
    var radios = div_ctrl.find("div").find("input");
    ctrls.each(function (i, o) {
        options += $(o).text() + '\n';
    });
    form.find("[name=name]").val(radios[0].name)
    form.find("[name=options]").val($.trim(options.replace(/\n\n/g, "")));
}
```

this function is reponsible to remove line break,

```
 form.find("[name=options]").val($.trim(options.replace(/\n\n/g, "")));
```

**But it is not working in firefox**

any help with this please

[image]

Comment: Try `.replace(/[\n\r]{2}/g, "")`

Comment: @Tushar , good catch pardon

Comment: not working , I am uploading the image where issue is occuring

Comment: Try `.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '')`. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: @Daenu not fine in firefox again

Comment: Add a fiddle please, with html

Comment: its using handlebar js , so its complex  to add jsfiddle , i can provide you the url to download and see the plugin that is creating issue https://github.com/anupshinde/demos/blob/gh-pages/form-builder-part2/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of problems:

1. `.replace` does not search across multiple lines by default
2. `.replace` does not continue past the first match by default
3. `/n` is actually preceded by whitespace (the carriage return `\r` character), so your test for `\n\n` will *never* match anything.

If you use a simple regular expression with the `global` and `multiline` flags, this will work:

```
.replace( /(?:\r?\n)+/gm, '\n' )
```

I've created a [small fiddle that demonstrates this](http://jsfiddle.net/rockerest/5jj8zrtx/2/), and also removes leading space from a line.

As you can see, I made the leading `\r` optional, since you indicate it's working in other browsers. You should note that this is probably due to something magic happening in other browsers to normalize: Windows uses `\r\n` and (most) other platforms use `\n`.

> That said, a visual `new line` in **print** is two things: a character to indicate that a new line should be begun, and a character to tell the text caret to return to the beginning of the line (now a brand new one). While in practice a new line is all that most text processors need, the technically correct new line indicator in typography is both `\n` and `\r`. This is sort of a fuzzy line between what lines are in the real world and what they are in computers. This is the Windows standard, and I like it because it represents the real thing. On the other hand, Unix and Mac OSX use only `\n` which I like because it is conceptually easy to remember `\n is a new line`. Regardless, you need to test for both.

Comment: @JotDhaliwal I wrote, tested, and posted this answer in Firefox, so I **know** it works in Firefox. If what I posted doesn't strip multiple lines, then something else you have in your code is causing errors. You should create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to demonstrate what isn't working.

Comment: @JotDhaliwal No, sorry. StackOverflow is a site about creating knowledge for everyone. As a side effect, sometimes individuals can solve their own problems. It's a win-win for everyone. Me helping you on TeamViewer helps no one but you. As a minor sidenote, I charge $275 / hr for that type of help, with a minimum of 1 hour billed: it would be worth your time to expend the effort here to elucidate your problem and get the free help.

Answer (score -1):

Try it : Use Below regular expression with replace for globally line breaker remover...

```
.replace( /(?:\n\r?)+/gm, '\n' )
```

Comment: Did you literally copy my code sample and post as your own answer? I have a moderately unusual whitespace style that almost no one I've seen replicates. This is pretty egregious.