# how do i put br in javascript .text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do i put `<br>` inside my text? I tried putting `<br>` but it doesn't work--it just displays the literal text `<br>` on screen

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
$('#win').text(winner+' <br /> '+'stars'+'  <br />  '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
```

Comment: replace `$('#win').text` with `$('#win').html`

Comment: I don't see any `br` tags in your code

Comment: Please re-add your code, the code is not syntatically correct at this time.

Comment: you should also know that using adding html this way is potencial security exploit. It can be used for XSS attack. You can probably find some filter that will prevent this to some degree ... maybe it is already integrated in jquery you should check it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add an HTML tag in text, but you want to see the *rendered* result!  `text` will escape the HTML characters.  If you want to *render* the HTML, then replace  `$('#win').text()` with `$('#win').html()`
eg :

```
 $('#win').html(winner+' <br /> '+'stars'+'  <br />  '+'earned'+' Completion time'+' '+ counter +' seconds');
```

see [jQuery text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

see [jQuery html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 0):

It would help you to use `$('#win').html()` instead of `$('#win').text()`.