# Add new line in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div like this

```
 <div class="sectionContent" contenteditable>
       <div class="capabilities" name="capabilities" >Some things</div>
 </div>
```

So i want everytime user type something in this div like

```
-Responsible,allways on time,love teamwork
-Willing to learn new things.
```

I will have new line after user press enter button.Here is the result i want.So how can i achivce that with js or jquery

```
-Responsible,allways on time,love teamwork</br>
-Willing to learn new things.</br>
```

Thanks for help.Kind regard

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: `contentediable` does this already by default. Not understanding what the problem is. See [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gakwc4ud/)

Comment: @charlietfl i'm use var capabilities = $('.capabilities').text(); to get the text in contentediable .But the result i get is [Here](http://prntscr.com/a19per)

Comment: use `html()` and you will have `<br>` in there already.

Comment: @charlietfl still not working [here](http://prntscr.com/a19qm5) is what i get when i use .html()

Comment: by the way, it's `<br>` or `<br/>` ... not sure '</br>` would do anything

Comment: ok...different results in different browsers. Chrome repeats the div and class and Firefox just adds `<br>`. You will need to parse differences or use an html editor probably for consistent results

Comment: @charlietfl i tried in chrome when you press enter it creates a new div that is why he is getting that result

Comment: I have [this](http://prntscr.com/a19syi) js function to add new line but here it's the [result](http://prntscr.com/a19t62) i get

Comment: Suggest you use an inline html editor script. Then you are assured consistent results cross browser

Comment: Is there another way to do