# Javascript - Remove '\n' from string

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var strObj = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{"text": true, ["text", "text", "text", "text"], [{ "text", "text" }]}\n\n\n'
```

I am trying to sanitize a string by stripping out the `\n` but when I do `.replace(/\\\n/g, '')` it doesn't seem to catch it. I also Google searched and found:

> ..in accordance with JavaScript regular expression syntax you need two backslash characters in your regular expression literals such as `/\\/` or `/\\/g`.

But even when I test the expression just to catch backslash, it returns false:
`(/\\\/g).test(strObj)`

RegEx tester captures `\n` correctly: http://regexr.com/3d3pe

Comment: Is that a typo in your .replace method? Shouldn't that be `/\\n/` not `/\\\n/`?

Comment: You only need one backslash: `/\n+/g`. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Should just be

```
.replace(/\n/g, '')
```

unless the string is actually

```
'\\n\\n\\n...
```

that it would be

```
.replace(/\\n/g, '')
```

Answer (score 21):

**No need of using RegEx** here, use [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```js
var strObj = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{"text": true, ["text", "text", "text", "text"], [{ "text", "text" }]}\n\n\n';
var trimmedStr = strObj.trim();

console.log('Before', strObj);
console.log('--------------------------------');
console.log('After', trimmedStr);
document.body.innerHTML = trimmedStr;
```

Comment: This is preferable over the regex answer IMO

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the backslashes.

```
var strObj = '\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n{"text": true, ["text", "text", "text", "text"], [{ "text", "text" }]}\n\n\n';

strObj.replace(/\n/g, '');
```

This code works as expected.

> "{"text": true, ["text", "text", "text", "text"], [{ "text", "text" }]}"