# ?: Notation in Regular Expression

Tags: regex

for one of my classes I have to describe the following regular expression:

```
\b4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})\b
```

I understand that it selects a number that: begins with 4, is followed by 12 digits (each between 0-9), and is followed by another 3 digits.

What I don't understand is the the question mark with the semicolon (?:....). I've tried looking online to find out what this means but the links I've found were somewhat confusing; I was hoping someone could give me a quick basic idea of what the question mark does in this example.

Comment: ?: is used to denote non capturing group. You can refer 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group

Answer (score 90):

This is going to be **short** answer.

When you use `(?:)` it means that the `group` is matched but is not captured for back-referencing i.e **non-capturing** group. It's not stored in memory to be referenced later on.

**For example:**

`(34)5\1`

This regex means that you are looking for `34` followed by `5` and then again `34`. Definitely you could write it as `34534` but sometimes the `captured group` is a complex pattern which you could not predict before hand.

So **whatever** is matched by **capturing group** should be appearing again.

[Regex101 demo for back-referencing](https://regex101.com/r/vH8gX6/2)

---

Back-referencing is also used while replacement.

**For Example:**

`([A-Z]+)[0-9]+`

This regex will look for `many` upper case letters followed by `many` digits. And I wish to replace this whole pattern just by **found** upper case letters.

Then I would **replace** whole pattern by using `\1` which stands for back-referencing **first** captured group.

[Regex101 demo for replacement](https://regex101.com/r/vH8gX6/1)

If you change to `(?:[A-Z]+)[0-9]+` this will no longer **capture** it and hence cannot be referenced back.

[Regex101 demo for non-capturing group](https://regex101.com/r/vH8gX6/3)

[A live answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524694/python-not-sure-how-to-build-following-regex/36524708#36524708)

Answer (score 15):

It's called a 'non-capturing group', which means the regex would *not* make a group by the match inside the parenteses like it would otherwise do (normally, a parenthesis creates a group).