# python - not sure how to build following regex

Tags: python, regex

I want to replace

```
'this is my string (anything within brackets)'
```

with

```
'this is my string '
```

a concrete sample would be:

```
'Blue Wire Connectors (35-Pack)'
```

should be replaced with

```
'Blue Wire Connectors '
```

can anyone suggest how to build this regex in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply search with `(\([^)]*\))` and replace with `empty string` `""`.

This regex is capturing everything within `(` `)` until a `)` is reached i.e end of parenthesis.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fR9yD0/1)

Comment: the capture group is useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Incase OP wishes to replace matched pattern with something else. And my bad habit.

Comment: even in this case it's useless.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Could be useful when appending with matched pattern. Like `something\1` or `\1something`.

Comment: It isn't the question here.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Okay.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern to be replaced should look about like that: `r'\(.*?\)'` which matches bracketed expressions non-greedily in order to avoid matching multiple bracketed expressions as one ([Python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)):

```
import re

s = 'this (more brackets) is my string (anything within brackets)'
x = re.sub(r'\(.*?\)', '', s)
# x: 'this  is my string '
```

Note, however, that nested brackets 'this (is (nested))' are a canonical example that cannot be properly handled by regular expressions.