# Remove first N lines on a character column in a data frame

Tags: r

I have a data frame containing emails. There is a column named "message" that looks like this:

```
> > dataset$message[1]  
>[1] Message-ID:...
> 
> Date: ...
> 
> From: ...
> 
> To:...
> 
> Subject: ...
> 
> Mime-Version: ...
> 
> Content-Type:...
> 
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: ...
> 
> X-From:...
> 
> X-To: ...
> 
> X-cc:...
> 
> X-bcc: ...
> 
> X-Folder: ...
> 
> X-Origin: ...
> 
> X-FileName: ...
>  
> > Some message text
```

In other words, each entry contains 15 lines of headers and then the text. What I want is to remove these 15 lines from each row and be left only with the text, so that

```
>dataset$message[1]
```

looks like this:

```
> Some message text
```

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) along with expected output. Also don't forget to post your attempt that failed. Cheers

Comment: Once the data is inside the data.frame it’s too late. You want to remove it *before* it gets read into the data.frame, e.g. by providing the appropriate arguments to `read.table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
sub("^(?:.*\\n){15}", "", multiline_string_mail, perl = TRUE)

#[1] "Super secret message"
```

example data: (you should always provide usable example data)

```
multiline_string_mail =
"hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
hehe
Super secret message"
```

Comment: What's the `?:` inside the regex?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524507/notation-in-regular-expression

Comment: This worked for a single entry of the data frame. I put it inside a loop and applied to every entry. Thanks a lot, I'm marking it as an answer.