# How to match typical tri-phone using regex?

Tags: python, regex

For example there is vowel and consonant phonemes in Chinese

```
vowels  = ['a', 'ai', 'an', 'ang', 'ao', 'e', 'ei', 'en', 'eng', 'er', 'i', 'ia', 'ian', 'iang', 'iao', 'ie', 'ii', 'iii', 'in', 'ing', 'iong', 'iou', 'o', 'ong', 'ou', 'u', 'ua', 'uai', 'uan', 'uang', 'uei', 'uen', 'ueng', 'uo', 'v', 'van', 've', 'vn', 'zh']

consonants = ['b','c','ch', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'sh',' sp', 'sil', 't', 'x', 'z']
```

Suppose I have tri-phone like this:

The tri-phone 'a-b+c' means previous,current,following phoneme is a,b and c.

[image]

I want to use regex to extract the adjacent vowels pattern like `vowel-vowel+*` and `*-vowel+vowel`.

For example

> Match: **zh-uei**+x, b-**ai+vn**, **e-uang**+x
>
> Don't match: sil-z+**ai**, **vn**-l+**v**, x-**ia**+f

I use this code:

```
v = '|'.join(vowels)           # Or v = '^'+'|'.join(consonants)
p = r'({0}\-{0}\+.*)|(.*\-{0}\+{0})'.format(v)
```

However `re.match(p,'z-en+iang')` still gives False. So how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: To help you get an answer faster, you might want to edit your answer so that a programmer with no experience in linguistics can answer it. It seems like it should be an easy solution, but it isn't totally clear what you're asking without looking up all the jargon.

Comment: @3ocene ok I will improve my question. Thank you

Comment: `\1` in regex matches exactly the contents (not the pattern) of group 1.

Comment: @MichaelButscher Thanks for point out, I try another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

vowels  = ['a', 'ai', 'an', 'ang', 'ao', 'e', 'ei', 'en', 'eng', 'er', 'i', 'ia', 'ian', 'iang', 'iao', 'ie', 'ii', 'iii', 'in', 'ing', 'iong', 'iou', 'o', 'ong', 'ou', 'u', 'ua', 'uai', 'uan', 'uang', 'uei', 'uen', 'ueng', 'uo', 'v', 'van', 've', 'vn', 'zh']
consonants = ['b','c','ch', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'sh','sp', 'sil', 't', 'x', 'z']
# joining vowels with |
vowels_string = '|'.join(vowels)
# joining consonants with |
consonants_string = '|'.join(consonants)

# joining all characters with |
all_chars = "{}|{}".format(vowels_string, consonants_string)

reg1 = '^(?:{1})-(?:{0})\+(?:{0})$'.format(vowels_string, all_chars) # allchars-vowel+vowel
reg2 = '^(?:{0})-(?:{0})\+(?:{1})$'.format(vowels_string, all_chars) # vowel-vowel+allchars 

# compiling the regex
regex = re.compile(
    '({})|({})'.format(reg1, reg2)
)

# testing
print(re.match(regex, 'zh-uei+x'))
print(re.match(regex, 'b-ai+vn'))
print(re.match(regex, 'e-uang+x'))
print(re.match(regex, 'z-en+iang'))

print(re.match(regex, 'sil-z+ai'))
print(re.match(regex, 'vn-l+v'))
print(re.match(regex, 'x-ia+f'))
```

- `vowels_string` contains all vowels separated with or (|)
- `consonants_string` contains all consonants separated with or (|)
- `all_chars` contains all the characters separated with or (|)

the regex is the following : (1 is `all_chars` and 0 is `vowels_string`)

```
'^ -> beginning of string
(?:{1})  -> all characters
-
(?:{0}) -> vowels
\+
(?:{0}) -> vowels
$'-> end of string
```

Comment: what the purpose of the sign `?:`?  If deleting it, the result change

Comment: @partida check out this post for ?: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524507/notation-in-regular-expression

Comment: I find `?:` means non-capturing group. It seems it's not effect the result only use less memory?

Comment: @partida it affects the results sometimes check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3513858/6147182 ... when you use a non capturing groupe (?:) the same happens while matching as when you use a normal capturing group () ... but in the results the string matched using the not capturing group is not returned, i just added them by force of habit, if you need the string to be returned remove the ?: