# extract word and before word and insert between ”_” in regex

Tags: python, regex

I need some help on declaring a regex. My inputs are like the following:

I need to extract word and before word and insert between ”_” in regex:python
 Input

```
 Input
 s2 = 'Some other medical terms and stuff diagnosis of R45.2 was entered for  this patient. Where did Doctor Who go? Then xxx feea fdsfd'
 # my regex pattern
 re.sub(r"(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,1}diagnosis", r"\1_", s2)
 Desired Output:
 s2 = 'Some other medical terms and stuff_diagnosis of R45.2 was entered      for this patient. Where did Doctor Who go? Then xxx feea fdsfd'
```

Comment: You have no capturing group but are using `\1` to refer to it .

Comment: Try `re.sub(r"[^\w'-]+(?=diagnosis)", "_", s2)`, see [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugW0q4/1).

Comment: What Wiktor tries to say is that groups must be captured example: `(?: text not captured ) ( text captured as \1 )+ (text captured as \2)?`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36524507/notation-in-regular-expression

Comment: Thanks a ton Its working

Comment: won't be `str.replace(' diagnosis ','_diagnosis')` much better ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have no capturing group defined in your regex, but are using `\1` placeholder (replacement backreference) to refer to it.

You want to replace 1+ special chars other than `-` and `'` before the word `diagnosis`, thus you may use

```
re.sub(r"[^\w'-]+(?=diagnosis)", "_", s2)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugW0q4/1/).

**Details**

- `[^\w'-]+` - any non-word char excluding `'` and `_`
- `(?=diagnosis)` - a positive lookahead that does not consume the text (does not add to the match value and thus `re.sub` does not remove this piece of text) but just requires `diagnosis` text to appear immediately to the right of the current location.

Or

```
re.sub(r"[^\w'-]+(diagnosis)", r"_\1", s2)
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ugW0q4/2). Here, `[^\w'-]+` also matches those special chars, but `(diagnosis)` is a [*capturing group*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) whose text can be referred to using the `\1` [placeholder](https://www.regular-expressions.info/replacebackref.html) from the replacement pattern.

**NOTE**: If you want to make sure `diagnosis` is matched as a whole word, use `\b` around it, `\bdiagnosis\b` (mind the `r` raw string literal prefix!).