# Convert unicode from Json in HTML with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, unicode

I am getting issues to convert unicode and render in a nice HTML code.

Here is the information i have as an input in my Json file

```
`"CLIENT:\r\n-Client1: Project1\u00c2\u00a0\r\n- Client2: etc..."`
```

I would like this to render as below in

`CLIENT:
- client1: Project 1
- Client2: etc...`

It currently renders like this :

```
`CLIENT: - Client1: Project1Â  - Client2: etc...`
```

I looked everywhere but could not find a function that could handle all unicodes to decode in nice html code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: please mention your code , it helps to give proper solution . You can achieve using regular expression.

Comment: \u00c2 is the correct unicode for Â, so I'm not sure what/why you're expecting different?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can take a look at this:
[How do I replace all line breaks in a string with 
 tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

You do this:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

before insert into the html.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript, you can use this fragment

```html
<script>
var c = decodeURIComponent(escape(`"CLIENT:\r\n-Client1: Project1\u00c2\u00a0\r\n- Client2: etc..."`));
   c = c.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '');
   c = c.replace(':-', ': - ');
   document.write(c);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to make this work with the below function:

```
function strFormat(str) {
    var c= decodeURIComponent(escape(str));
    c= c.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
    c= c.replace(':-', ': - ');
    return c;

}
```

Let me know if there are any cleaner way to do this?