# How to detect line break and remove everything line break

Tags: javascript

I have manage to detect a line break in a string, but have can i remove it properly so in string would be only left  "First Line"

```
var str = "First Line"         
+"\nSecond Text Line";

var res = /\r|\n/.exec(str);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: `console.log( str.split("\n")[0] );`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways, but if you may have `\r` *or* `\n`, I'd probably use `replace` with a regex:

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r|\n).*$/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex:

```js
var str = "First Line" + "\n Second Text Line";
var line = str.replace(/(?:\r|\n).*$/, '');
console.log(line);
```

Answer (score -1):

split string using a "\n" as a delimeter and then join the string back together

```
var strings = str.split("\n");
var finalstr =strings[0];
```

Comment: OP clearly states not be interested in contents of `strings[1]`.