# angular binding removing returns

Tags: html, angularjs, string

It seems that binding removes returns from a string.

```
<div>{{obj.progress}}</div>
```

when I inspect the object in the console I get:

[image]

but in the HTML I see:

[image]

I would like the words to be displayed with the returns like:

```
block 1



block 2

...
```

Can I force the returns?

I have tried using ng-bind-html and ng-bind as well.

Comment: and you're positive this has nothing to do with the fact that browsers don't render returns in html other than within pre and/or code blocks, or with css `white-space`?

Comment: @KevinB I did not know that could be the case, very insightful.

Comment: I was able to solve this issue with this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags