# <p> tag putting all text on one line when line breaks exist

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically I have a webpage that is displaying a description for a client of a case.

What is happening is this description then gets displayed within a paragraph tag but it is placing everything on one line. Normally this occurs when you have a paragraph tag but the string is too long and it overflows, but this isn't the case here.

Example.

This is how the description shows in the webpage.

```
 Description

 hjkhjkhj sfgsdfgsdfghjkfjkfghjfghjfgh hjkgh jhkfghjkghjkgh jhkghjkg fjghjfghjfghjfghj fghdfhd fghfgdhfghdfghd  x  x x  ^^^^^^
```

When I go into the DOM explorer and look at the

tag itself this is what it shows me.

```
<p>hjkhjkhj


sfgsdfgsdfghjkfjkfghjfghjfgh

hjkgh
jhkfghjkghjkgh
jhkghjkg
fjghjfghjfghjfghj

fghdfhd


fghfgdhfghdfghd

 &nbsp;x&nbsp;
 x&nbsp;x&nbsp;





                            ^^^^^^</p>
```

It is showing the line breaks where they are supposed to occur, but this doesn't translate to the webpage itself.

Just wondering if anyone has come across this before? Or if anyone knows some CSS that will get around this problem.

Comment: because `\n` is not a `<br/>`. Extra Whitespace in HTML is ignored

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: Have you tried using `<br>` instead?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML "collapses" successive whitespace characters, and more importantly, it treats literal "line break characters" as just plain whitespace:

> A line break is defined to be a carriage return (`&#x000D;`), a line feed (`&#x000A;`), or a carriage return/line feed pair. All line breaks constitute white space.
>
> ([source](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/text.html#whitespace))

---

In this example, even though we have multiple carriage returns between "hello" and "world," it still treats it as just one whitespace character.

```html
<p>
  Hello
  
  
  
  World
</p>
```

---

In this example, we have no whitespace between "hello" and "world," but because we introduce the [line break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) element `<br>`, we do introduce a true line break.

```html
<p>
  Hello<br>World
</p>
```

---

As others have mentioned, if you would like to maintain the whitespace without introducing `<br>` elements, you can use CSS to **preformat** your paragraph tag. Namely, use the `white-space` attribute ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)) and change its value to `pre-wrap`.

```css
p {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Whitespace here
  
  is      maintained!
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked for me, the other answer does this as well but you provided extra info so I'll accept this one.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily do this with css. Something like

```
p {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

would work. There are also other options, such as `pre-wrap` and `pre-line`. The differences can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space).

```css
p {
  white-space: pre;  
}
```

```html
<p>hjkhjkhj


sfgsdfgsdfghjkfjkfghjfghjfgh

hjkgh
jhkfghjkghjkgh
jhkghjkg
fjghjfghjfghjfghj

fghdfhd


fghfgdhfghdfghd

 &nbsp;x&nbsp;
 x&nbsp;x&nbsp;





                            ^^^^^^</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

To break a line you can simply use the tag `<b/>` or you define a width

just like that

```
width:300px;
```

Comment: I would use `display: block` if I wanted something to be on it's own line