# Keep line breaks in outputed div from textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="height:50px;">
1. test
2. test
3. test
</textarea>

<div style="word-break: break-all;"></div>
```

I would like to make the text appear in div in the exact manner as it appears in textarea.

I've tried to css div with `word-break`, etc. but none has worked.

Note: specifically, I just want to know how to do it within a div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: also, you could try using an event listener like `change` to update the `div` as the user types instead of waiting for the field to lose focus with `blur`.

Comment: @Moose ya i know that i just want my helpers to see the result instantly instead of putting something in themselves.

Comment: @Nico that question does not seem to be anywhere close to what im lookin for.

Comment: @Will one downfall of using `white-space:pre` is it will act as a pre tag. This formatting of long lines text will expand horizontally and will not break (word wrap). Now if thats the intention then  fine. See this use case https://jsfiddle.net/yg9jv3o4/3/

Comment: @Nico didn't realize that. thanks for the headsup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting `white-space:pre;` or `white-space:pre-wrap;` to the div.

```js
$("textarea").blur(function() {
  $("div").html($("textarea").val());
});

$("textarea").blur();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="height:50px;">
1. test
2. test
3. test
</textarea>

<div style="white-space:pre;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to be able to export it to HTML.

```
str = str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />');
```

Reference: [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)