# replace '\r\n' with '< br>' in Text area javascript?

Tags: jquery

when I press Enter I want to insert `"< br >"` instead of the new line `'\n\r'`in my text area,
Exemple:

i want the text in the text area  to be:

```
"hello <br> dear",
```

instead of

```
"hello
dear"
```

I tried this code but with no luck:

```
$('#inputText').bind('keyup', function(e) {
   var data = $('#inputText').val();
   $('#inputText').text(data.replace(/\n/g, "<br />"));
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you not need to do that if you're using the standard `<input>` or `<textarea>`?

Comment: Maybe you're shoehorning yourself here.  I doubt you need the `<br>` to be visible as you're typing.  Wouldn't it be better to convert the data after the fact?  If it's stored into a database, you could convert the data just before the insert/update.

Comment: no i really need it to be visible, is there a way for that?

Comment: show it then save it

Comment: Basically the same as https://stackoverflow.com/q/784539/215552

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will work fine if:-

1.`bind()` converted to `on()`(because `bind()` is deprecated)

2.`text()`  need to be `.val()`

Working example (check comments too):-

```js
// applied mouseout to prevent repetition on each key-press

//you can apply keyup also no problem

$('#inputText').on('mouseout', function(e) {
  var data = $('#inputText').val();
  $('#inputText').val(data.replace(/\n/g, "<br />")); // text() need be val()
}); // here ); missing in your given code
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="inputText"></textarea>
```