# ExpressJS/JS - new line of text

Tags: mongoose

suppose I have a from with data that looks like this: http://prntscr.com/gfh0nd
Data from form are sended to database - String type (mongoose).

Now how Can I put br tag or new p tag exactly where I did new line with enter key?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: Ok, but... To make it work I need to put it in {{{body}}}.. That means that user can take advantage of that and use f.e <strong> and other tags.

Answer (score 0):

I find the way. Just use

```
white-space: pre-line;
```

to ur p tag in css :)