# How transform a string with a particular identifier?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
Input: 'text __city__ text __city__ text __city__'

Output: 'text <i>city</i> text <i>city</i> text <i>city</i>'
```

The result of the feature is passed into [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://zhenyong.github.io/react/tips/dangerously-set-inner-html.html).

This component is

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: content.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br />')}}></div>
```

for this problem ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)).

My function is

```
const transformText = (text) => {
  const tmp = text.split('__');
  var res = '';
  var check = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length-1; i++){
    check = !check;
    if (check) {
      res += '<i>'+tmp[i]+'</i>';
    } else if (tmp[i] != undefined){
      res += tmp[i];
    }
  }
  return res;
};
```

but breaks the rest of the page into IE11 browser.

Comment: First of all, if your raw input is not HTML, turning it into HTML and then use `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` is a terrible idea. When transforming your input, your first goal should be to parse it into an array or hash of text/city pairs. Once that is done, you would only need to iterate over that array and render each pair accordingly, using `<li>` tags for instance, or in a table if that's your preference. On top of it, you would gain granular, individual access to each pair to be able to do whatever you pleased.

Comment: It's not a list, it was just an example. From the API I get a string.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry, but I can only comment on the code you provide. And in that particular case, your approach is terribly wrong, as I outlined in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: transforming the input text.

Assuming the input is in the form `"text __city__ text __city__ ... text 
__city__"` as per your example.

```
const input = "text1 __paris__ text2 __london__ text3 __berlin__";
// the following will turn the input into an array of the form
// [ [text, city], [text, city], ... [text, city] ]
const pairs = input.slice(0, -2).split('__ ').map(pair => pair.split(' __'));
```

Step 2: using the array in a React component.

Assuming the variable `pairs` holds the text/city pairs as defined above, the following would be the `render` method inside your component (if it is class-based).

```
render() {
  return (
    <ul>
      {pairs.map((pair, index) => {
        return <li key={index}>{pair[0]} <i>{pair[1]}</i></li>;
      })}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: The string can also be '__city__ text __city__'. They are not pairs of values.

Comment: Resolved

const tmp = quote.title.split('__');

{tmp.map((e, key) => (key%2 == 1 ? <i>{e}</i> : e))}

Comment: @GiGa Again, I could only rely on the example you provided to determine the format of your input. If it is different, you can easily adapt the solution to fit different input formats (as you did in your previous comment). What really matters here is the general approach, and as you can see, this is much better (and much more React-like) than your original inclination to manipulate and operate directly on a single string.

Comment: The approach is definitely better. Thanks Jaxx