# How do I replace the line breaks in a textarea by a <br/>

Tags: javascript, html

I formed a `textarea` and a button that replaces the line breaks of this `textarea` with `<br />` tags.

**Code:**

```js
var gtcontbtnafterTA = document.getElementById("contbtnafterTA");
var gtRequesttextarea = document.getElementById("Requesttextarea");

gtcontbtnafterTA.onclick = function(event) {
  "use strict";
  Requesttextarea.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'), '<br/>');
}
```

```css
#Requesttextarea {
  font-family: Traditional Arabic;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #000099;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px double #FF0000
}

#contbtnafterTA {
  font-family: Traditional Arabic;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #0000FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 450
}
```

```html
<p><textarea rows="50" name="Requesttextarea" cols="50" dir="rtl" id="Requesttextarea"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="button" value="الخطوات التالية" name="contbtnafterTA" dir="rtl" id="contbtnafterTA" class="buttonstyles"></p>
```

**Resulting error:**

[image]

Object doesn't support property or method `replace`:

I hope I can get some code that replaces linebreaks with `<br />` tags

---

Here are some pictures to explain the desired outcome.

**Before:**

[image]

**After:**

[image]

There is one line and some `<br />` tags replacing each new line

Comment: You need to access the _value_  of the textarea … read it, replace in there, write it back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: Instead of `Requesttextarea.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'), '<br/>');` try this: `gtRequesttextarea.value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'), '<br/>');`

Comment: 1) Your question looks [duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

2) Check your textarea's variable. in onclick function it's wrong
3) You've to replace it's value

Comment: @CBroe > I will try your route, Thank You.

Comment: @Brissy , I checked The full topic. There are frequent question, but there is no suitable solution for my this simple case. That's why I added a specific question. I'm sorry.

Comment: @r3dst0rm , I tried , The textarea doesn't change , but the error code hasn't been shown now.

Comment: You have to reassign the value again like so: `gtRequesttextarea.value = gtRequesttextarea.value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'), '<br/>');`

Comment: @r3dst0rm, >  Well, I understand you. I will try now. Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to access the textarea value

```js
var gtcontbtnafterTA = document.getElementById("contbtnafterTA");
var gtRequesttextarea = document.getElementById("Requesttextarea");

gtcontbtnafterTA.onclick = function(event) {
  "use strict";
  Requesttextarea.value = Requesttextarea.value.replace(new RegExp('\r?\n', 'g'), '<br/>');
}
```

```css
#Requesttextarea {
  font-family: Traditional Arabic;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #000099;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  direction: rtl;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px double #FF0000
}

#contbtnafterTA {
  font-family: Traditional Arabic;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #0000FF;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 450
}
```

```html
<p><textarea rows="50" name="Requesttextarea" cols="50" dir="rtl" id="Requesttextarea"></textarea></p>
<p><input type="button" value="الخطوات التالية" name="contbtnafterTA" dir="rtl" id="contbtnafterTA" class="buttonstyles"></p>
```