# How to add a new line in MySql when user hits 'enter' in textarea?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Whenever user enters text in textarea field,the data is saved in MySql database using php and ajax.

The problem is that data gets saved in mysql in a straight line without line breaks even if the user hits 'enter'.

Please help me .If you could give code,that would be awesome.

Comment: I'd guess `nl2br` is what you are after.

Comment: Are you sure the line break is not being saved in the database column? Where are you trying to display it? If it's in HTML you'll need to replace the line break `\n\r` with a `<\br>` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags

Comment: @user3783243 would it need to place additional <br> tags at the place where enter was hit?

Comment: @Gabriel I am displaying it in html

Comment: A `<br>` in place of `\n` should be the same as what was entered. If you want to double space use 2.