# replace() not functioning as expected attempting to replace newline characters (/n /rn /r) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have just started using JavaScript so this could just be a syntax error that I am overlooking or could be a regex error but the source of the code seemed to be well accepted.

I got my code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags) question.

If I pass the String `This is a string \n` It doesn't replace the `\n` and outputs to the webpage `This is a string \n`.

**My code follows:**

```
<p id="commandOutput">Click run and it will output here</p>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var exampleSocket = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080/ws")

    var update = function(){
        exampleSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
            document.getElementById("commandOutput").innerHTML = event.data.toString().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br/>");
        }
    };

    window.setTimeout(update);

</script>
```

**My question refers to this line:**

```
 document.getElementById("commandOutput").innerHTML = event.data.toString().replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br/>");
```

Comment: The regular expression operates on the special control characters for carriage return and newline, not on literal `\n`.

Comment: @Pointy Ah, I see. How would I add the literal `\n` because the string I am passing has been constructed using the literal `\n`

Comment: Use `\\n` to mask the backslash.

Comment: @ChrisG Thank you! Works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Pointy mentioned the problem is:

> The regular expression operates on the special control characters for carriage return and newline, not on literal `\n`

As @ChrisG mentioned, to get around this you can:

> **Use `\\n` to mask the backslash**