# How to replace \n with <br> in JSON string?

Tags: javascript, string, reactjs

I'm getting the following raw string from a JSON file. I console.log it display fine.

```
"Hello, my name is Jane, from "IStaff" company.\r\n\r\n.We are interested in your service.\r\n\r\n.Please call me back "
```

When I rendering this string, there is no new lines.

Comment: How exactly are you trying to insert it into the `<div>`? The code matters

Comment: New lines won't display in the browser. You need to use `<br>` tag for a new line on the browser. Use [nl2br](http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php)  to parse your JSON and convert all new lines to break tags before sending to client side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the best way in my case is just add in css : white-space: pre-wrap;

Answer (score 1):

If you insert that string into HTML, it will render by literally showing the `\n` and `\r` elements:

```js
const string = 'Hello, my name is Jane, from "IStaff" company.\r\n\r\n.We are interested in your service.\r\n\r\n.Please call me back';
document.write(string);
```

You need to replace them with HTML `<br>` elements:

```js
const string = 'Hello, my name is Jane, from "IStaff" company.\r\n\r\n.We are interested in your service.\r\n\r\n.Please call me back';
const renderString = string.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br>");
document.write(renderString);
```

Regex above from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/10221765).

Answer (score 1):

I think this problem occurs when you use innerHTML, use `<br/>` instead of /r/n.

Example:

```
"Hello, my name is Jane, from 'IStaff' company.<br/> <br/> .We are interested in your service.<br/> <br/> .Please call me back "
```

"Hello, my name is Jane, from 'IStaff' company.
 
 .We are interested in your service.
 
 .Please call me back "

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace characters like newlines do not render in HTML. You have to change the `\n` into `<br>`

```js
function nl2br(str, is_xhtml) {
  if (typeof str === 'undefined' || str === null) {
    return '';
  }
  var breakTag = (is_xhtml || typeof is_xhtml === 'undefined') ? '<br />' : '<br>';
  return (str + '').replace(/([^>\r\n]?)(\r\n|\n\r|\r|\n)/g, '$1' + breakTag + '$2');
}

dataReceveid = function(json) {
  $("div").html(nl2br(json.str));
}

$(function() {
  dataReceveid({
    str: '"Hello, my name is Jane, from "IStaff" company.\r\n\r\n.We are interested in your service.\r\n\r\n.Please call me back "'
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: where you get is_xhtml value? I'm not good at jquery , could please make with plain js?

Comment: is_xhtml is not mandatory(no need to pass), it is their to handle if u are inserting string in the xhtml then u have to pass true.

Comment: one more thing it is not related to jquery anyways

Comment: <br> displays as a plain text. Is it possible to get a raw srting and then insert <br> tags?

Comment: sorry didn't get u, <br> displays as a plain text?? where are u displaying in html ? (div, textbox, textarea)

Comment: here how it looks like:" Hello, my name is Jane, from "IStaff" company.<br><br>.We are interested in your service.<br><br>.Please call me back."
I'm displaying it in div tag

Answer (score 0):

The browser doesn't know what does it means `\r\n`. The language the web browser know only is `HTML` and `\r\n` is not an `HTML` language word. To break the line in the browser you have to use `HTML` language tag `<br />` so the browser can consider it and break the lines.

So the simple solution to your problem is replacing `\r\n` with `<br />` HTML tag/element.