# MySQL not adding new line in HTML

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Using NodeJS and ExpressJS, im passing in the data from MySQl it has new lines but not when i show it on my HTML pages, heres proof it shows new lines (random text)

[the text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uZAJl.png)

[results from database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nqo6D.png)

[the html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koekX.png)

and this is the code when rending in the html

```html
<span><%=userRoles[0].description%></span>
```

i need it to add the new lines of its in the row

Comment: Q: Do you know that "\r\n" newlines in your HTML text will *NOT* appear as line breaks when you view them in the browser?  Your two options to display linefeeds in HTML are !) use the [<pre>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) tag,or 2) to a text substitution of `\r\n` to `<br/>\r\n`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Method 1: replace all line breaks(`\r\n`,`\r`,`\n`) with `<br>` tag

You need to use `<%- code %>` instead of `<%= code %>` to avoid the html escape.

```
<span><%- userRoles[0].description.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>'); %></span>
```

- https://github.com/tj/ejs/issues/187
- [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

#### Method 2: use `<pre>` tag

the `<pre>` element will display the line breaks

```
<pre><%- userRoles[0].description %></pre>
```

- https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp