# problem with ".replaceWith" (don't work) when use "nl2br()"and use "Enter" in database text

Tags: php, jquery

I have a text displayed from database and I create a "Edit Text" button to edit it and save it. It works when the text from database is in one line but if I use an <kbd>enter</kbd> to text for going to the new line it doesn't work at all.

I remove the getting text from database part for easier testing that:

```
<?php
$rr="asdadsasd \n d"; 
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="submit"  id="edp"value="EditPst">
<div class="post"id="pst"><?php echo nl2br($rr);?></div>
</form>
<script>
$(document).on("click", "#edp", function() { 
    $("#edp").replaceWith('');
    $("#pst").replaceWith('<textarea name="pps" class="post"id="pss"><?php echo nl2br($rr);?></textarea><input type="submit"  id="spp" value="save"name="svpst"><input type="submit"  id="canp" value="cansel">');
});
</script>
```

If you remove the `\n` part it works fine.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by *it doesn't work*. Do you see an error in Console?  Since the content inside the element doesn't matter, it should work as expected. What were you expecting to have happen?

Comment: if you just add a jquery.js file link and test it with "\n" in "$rr" variable and without it you find out the problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-tags)

Comment: this creates another problem, when i change "\n" with <br> when i click on edit text , in the edit text show the <br> element

Answer (score -2):

I am unable to replicate the issue as you described it. PHP `nl2br()` just adds `<br />` elements when it detects a New Line (`\n`) character.

> nl2br — Inserts HTML line breaks before all newlines in a string
>
> Returns `string` with `<br />` or `<br>` inserted before all newlines (`\r\n`, `\n\r`, `\n` and `\r`).

Test with the following, excluding PHP that cannot be processed.

```js
$(function() {
  $.fn.nl2br = function() {
    var re = RegExp("(?:\r\n|\r|\n)", 'g');
    var str = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(str.replace(re, "<br>"));
  }
  $("form").on("click", "#edp", function() {
    $("#edp").remove();
    var cnt = $("#pst").html();
    $("#pst").replaceWith('<textarea name="pps" class="post"id="pss"></textarea><input type="submit" id="spp" value="Save"name="svpst" /><input type="submit"  id="canp" value="Cancel" />');
    $("#pss").html(cnt);
  });
  $("form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#pss").nl2br();
    //return true;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="">
  <input type="submit" id="edp" value="EditPst">
  <div class="post" id="pst">asdadsasd <br /> d</div>
</form>
```

Comment: problem of your answer is when i use an enter and send the text it to  the database it save with "\n" not <br>

Comment: @behzad that would be expected as the `\r\n` would appear in the `<textarea>` content. Sounds like you need to convert NL to HTML before sending the code back to the Database, either in JS or in PHP.

Comment: i don't understand what you mean

Comment: @behzad I updated my answer a bit. Again it's not clear what you are expecting or desire.