# Display text format with break lines - Jquery

Tags: jquery

I store a text in my database as

`$dataStorage = "This is my short string.\n\nThank you."` When i fetch the string from database and display in input box or text area, It appears just as it is stored in the database (i.e with the new break line" as below

```
This is a short string. 

Thank you.
```

Now, i am trying to display the text in div. The text appears but the new lines do not show. So it appears like

```
This is a short string.Thank you
```

How can i fix this using jquery

**HTML**

```
<div class="chat-content rounded" id="msg">
</div>
```

**JS**

//result is the string from the database

```
$('#msg').val(result);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I replace all line breaks in a string with <br /> elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784539/how-do-i-replace-all-line-breaks-in-a-string-with-br-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the newlines by br:

```
result.replace(/\n/g,"<br />");
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using PHP to fetch the text string from the database? Then you can apply `nl2br($your_text)` to the fetched result, which converts the new-line commands to HTML linebreaks (`<br/>`)