# Including "\n" in FormData

Tags: javascript, html, forms, textarea

I have a form and one of the fields is textarea

How do I send this data so that the new lines(\n) will be included and will be saved into the database?

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. If you have a problem, provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Since I got it working, I'm just gonna answer my own question:

I got it working by using regex.

`str.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>')` will do the thing.

from : https://stackoverflow.com/a/784547/15382725

Comment: This answers a different question (which is how to render new lines in an HTML document).

Comment: Yes it is, but I can convert new lines to literal <br> and save it to database and render it using innerHTML.